# How to add multi let operator and orderby in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have more columns in datatable (about 100 columns). See examble below:

```
 Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | ..... | Column n 
 1;Nick   | 1        | USA      | ..... | Value 1
 2;David  | 2        | Reston   | ..... | Value 2
 3;Marry  | 3        | Spain    | ..... | Value 3
 4;Join   | 4        | Italy 3  | .....  Value 4
```

```
Dictionary<string, string > dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("Column_1", "asc");
dict.Add("Column_2", "asc");
dict.Add("Column_1", "desc");
...................
dict.Add("Column_n", "asc");

var myRows = from row in datatable.AsEnumerable()
             let myID = int.Parse(row.Field<string>("Column 2"))
             let name = row.Field<string>("Column 1").Split(';')[1]
             ....
             orderby myID ascending, name descending, ......, column n asc
             select row;
```

My problem is how to loop all items in Dictionary to add more **let** statements and **orderby** all columns in Dictionary.

Please help me to fix it. My english is not good, sorry

Comment: maybe something like :http://stackoverflow.com/q/41244/1698987 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<string, string > dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("col1", "ASC");
dict.Add("col2", "ASC");
dict.Add("col3", "DESC");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("col1");
dt.Columns.Add("col2");
dt.Columns.Add("col3");
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    dt.Rows.Add(r.Next(10), r.Next(4), r.Next(2));
string sort = "";
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dict)
    sort = sort + " " + entry.Key + " " + entry.Value + ",";
sort = sort.Substring(0, sort.Length - 1).Trim();
dt.DefaultView.Sort = sort;
dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Comment: Nice. I'd use a string builder, but other than that, great :)

Comment: Could i use linq to do that. I don't want to use dataview. Because i have to custom value before sorting. Ex: I need to split(';') value column 1

Comment: What you need is [Dynamic LINQ Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).
Ps: you can prepare data before passing it to datatable too :)